# Holomorphic sectional curvature of complex projective spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I have heard that the holomorphic sectional curvature of the complex projective space (w.r.t the Fubini Study metric) is 2. Can anyone give me a self-contained reference to this fact, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where have you heard this? What have you tried to calculate? As is the case with spheres, the answer depends on the normalization of the metric and the corresponding “radius.”

Comment: I don't recall a reference where this is calculated, but it is a very good exercise to work this out for yourself. I recommend calculating the Chern connection of the Fubini-Study metric first, then the curvature form, and from that the curvature tensor. For the connection, it's better to use that $\partial_\nu h(\xi, \bar \eta) = h(D_\nu \xi, \bar \eta)$ for holomorphic sections than to try to use the matrix representation of the connection.

Comment: Hint: It suffices to work out the case of $CP^1$ and then use symmetries of $CP^n$ with respect to the Fubini-Study metric.

Comment: Here would be one source of how they calculate it but it is not self-contained: [link] (https://math.ecnu.edu.cn/~bliu/files/Complex_manifolds_and_Kaehler_geometry/3.%20Holomorphic%20sectional%20curvature.pdf)

Comment: I have no idea what you think self-contained should mean. We cannot give you an entire course in differential geometry. If I were to do this computation, it would be with moving frames and differential forms. We have absolutely no idea what tools you have and what your knowledge base is. I suggest you pick up Kobayashi-Nomizu, start on p. 169 of volume 2, and work your way backwards to acquire the necessary knowledge.